# error during upgrade liferay 5.2.3 to 6.0.6 Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: liferay, upgrade

i am trying to upgrade liferay 5.2.3 to 6.0.6 and this code occurred that exception
primary key in tagsAsset table is equal primary key in assetEntry table and this code wants to select from tagsAsset and insert into assetEntry that occurred Exception 
 :

```
con = DataAccess.getConnection();

        ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from TagsAsset");

        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            long assetId = rs.getLong("assetId");
            long groupId = rs.getLong("groupId");
            long companyId = rs.getLong("companyId");
            long userId = rs.getLong("userId");
            String userName = rs.getString("userName");
            Timestamp createDate = rs.getTimestamp("createDate");
            Timestamp modifiedDate = rs.getTimestamp("modifiedDate");
            long classNameId = rs.getLong("classNameId");
            long classPK = rs.getLong("classPK");
            boolean visible = rs.getBoolean("visible");
            Timestamp startDate = rs.getTimestamp("startDate");
            Timestamp endDate = rs.getTimestamp("endDate");
            Timestamp publishDate = rs.getTimestamp("publishDate");
            Timestamp expirationDate = rs.getTimestamp("expirationDate");
            String mimeType = rs.getString("mimeType");
            String title = rs.getString("title");
            String description = rs.getString("description");
            String summary = rs.getString("summary");
            String url = rs.getString("url");
            int height = rs.getInt("height");
            int width = rs.getInt("width");
            double priority = rs.getDouble("priority");
            int viewCount = rs.getInt("viewCount");

            addEntry(
                assetId, groupId, companyId, userId, userName, createDate,
                modifiedDate, classNameId, classPK, visible, startDate,
                endDate, publishDate, expirationDate, mimeType, title,
                description, summary, url, height, width, priority,
                viewCount);
```

Comment: Is this custom code? Which exception occurs where?

Comment: It was resolved.tanks